# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSDictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>' to 'NSMutableDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdictionary

I have an App written in Swift 3.0 and I declared the following data types:

```
var movies = [Movie]()
var getPlist = NSMutableDictionary()
var movieItems = NSMutableDictionary()
```

And I have the following method which is loading the content of a plist:

```
// Connect to plist and get the data
    if let plist = PlistHandler(name: "MovieData") {
        getPlist = plist.getMutablePlistDict()!

        // Load the movie items into the table view data source
        for i in 0..<getPlist.count {
            movieItems = (getPlist.object(forKey: "Item\(i)") as! NSMutableDictionary) as! [String: String] as! NSMutableDictionary
            let newName = movieItems.object(forKey: "Name")
            let newRemark = movieItems.object(forKey: "Remark")
            if newName as? String != "" {
                movies.append(Movie(name: newName as? String, remark: newRemark as? String)
            )}
        }
    } else {
        print("Unable to get Plist")
    }
```

It calls a method called getMutablePlistDict() from another class:

```
// Get the values from plist -> MutableDirectory
func getMutablePlistDict() -> NSMutableDictionary? {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destPath!) {
        guard let dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: destPath!) else { return .none }
        return dict
    } else {
        return .none
    }
}
```

When I run the App I get the error above (see question title). But this is new. In Xcode 8 I didn't get this error. What is the reason for this and how I have to change my code to avoid that?

Comment: The syntax `as! NSMutableDictionary) as! [String: String] as! NSMutableDictionary` is horrible. The error message is pretty clear. You cannot cast a Swift dictionary to `NSMutableDictionary`. **Don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all**. Declare the dictionary as `[String:String]`. With the `var` keyword you get mutability for free. And instead `NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile` use `PropertyListSerialization`

Comment: Thank‘s for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this :

Changed `NSMutableDictionary` to `[String: Any]` :

```
var movies = [Movie]()
var getPlist: [String: Any] = [:]
var movieItems: [String: Any] = [:]


func getMutablePlistDict() -> [String: Any] {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destPath!) {
        if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: destPath!) as? [String: Any] {
            return dict
        }
    } else {
        return [:]
    }
}

if let plist = PlistHandler(name: "MovieData") {
        let getPlist = plist.getMutablePlistDict()

        // Load the movie items into the table view data source
        for i in 0..<getPlist.count {
            if let movieItemsCheck = getPlist["Item\(i)"] as? [String: Any] {
                movieItems = movieItemsCheck
                if let newName = movieItems["Name"] as? String, let newRemark = movieItems["Remark"] as? String, newName != "" {
                    movies.append(Movie(name: newName, remark: newRemark))
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Unable to get Plist")
    }
```

Comment: Works fine, but there is a return missing in ‚if let dict = ... return dict } else { return [:]